# Android App Inventor: How do I set up a HTTPS connection?

Tags: android, authentication, https, app-inventor

I am making an app, with a very limited audience that logs into my mini website. It uses a HTTPS login dialog box though to access the site. How would I implement a setup where the user logs in with a username and password box on the first screen, submits the info with a button, which is used to log into the website, and then the user is taken to the next screen where there is a web viewer that is logged into and viewing the protected website.

This needs to be on Android and made in App Inventor, and I am quite clueless in programming, with little experience beyond hello world! :D I can string together some basic apps but here I am stumped. Please help! I just need some clear instruction really on what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Though your question is nearly one year old, I pass you a solution in case you still require it. Like you I came accross the need of creating a login dialog in AppInventor and none of the solutions I found on the web met completely my idea so I decided to develop it on my own.
The solution can be used as a template for any new app and it provides the following functionalities:

- Initial login window, with buttons allowing to register or remember password (by email)
- User's information stored in a tinywebDB, with basic encryption for password
- Integration with Google accounts, allowing the user to inform his google account instead of having to remember yet another password
- Profile window, allowing the user to modify its setting after its registration

The sources are [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1e4mf9UAhC0NHA1VDBZVG1scnM/edit?usp=sharing). I've also created a tutorial on my website. And [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=appinventor.ai_marcelubach.FesDeTito&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImFwcGludmVudG9yLmFpX21hcmNlbHViYWNoLkZlc0RlVGl0byJd) is a real app using this template.

Comment: **+1** great example Marcel! you put a lot of work into it! Can you provide a link to the tutorial mentioned?

Comment: Glad you liked it Taifun. As you can see in the tutorial there are quite a few pieces inspired in yout snippets!